How to add a js script file in Vue3 Vite?
<template>
    <component src="@/js/code1.js" :is="'script'"></component>   //not work?
    <component src="../js/code1.js" :is="'script'"></component>   //not work?
    <component src="./js/code1.js" :is="'script'"></component>   //not work?
    <img src="@/js/logo.png"/>   //work as expected
    <img src="../js/logo.png"/>   //work as expected
    <img src="./js/logo.png"/>   //not work as expected
</template>

"code1.js" and "logo.png" are in the same "js" folder.
In Vue3 Vite, URL automatically resolved for the different folder path of dev and production builds. But it do not work in script tag. How to add a JS script file in the Vue3, which should work in both dev and production builds?

I think that you can still import scripts like that. You could maybe also use this approach, even tho I do not really see a decent use-case for it tbh. Also, why do you not slap an inline CDN link or use the usual way of import X from Y.js in the script part of your file? As for the image, . means current directory, while .. means parent directory, hence not really a builder/Vue/other issue but more of you properly navigating the architecture of your project.
